# A string replace with array

Tags: plugins, joomla

I am trying to create a simple image gallery for joomla 3. I have managed to get the code working. The way it works is that, it detects the string `{dGalley}stories{/dGallery}` from article. I have done this so far. It works but it only prints one image. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgContentgallery extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentPrepare($content, $article, $params, $limit){

        preg_match_all('/{dGallery}(.*?){\/dGallery}/is', $article->text, $matches);

        $i=0;

        foreach ($matches[1] as $value)
        {

            $result = array(); 

            $dir = '/home/juniorwe/public_html/images/'.$matches[1][$i];

            $cdir = scandir($dir); 

            foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
            { 
                if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
                { 
                    if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
                    { 
                        $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        $article->text = str_replace('{dGallery}'.$matches[1][$i].'{/dGallery}','<img src="../images/'.$matches[1][$i].'/'.$value.'"/>
', $article->text);

                    } 
                }

            } 
            $i++;
        }

    }

}
```

Updated code. It works but a bit dirty solution:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class PlgContentgallery extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentPrepare($content, $article, $params, $limit)
    {

        $document = JFactory::getDocument();

        $document->addScript(JURI::base(). "plugins/content/gallery/jquery.colorbox.js");
        $document->addScript(JURI::base(). "plugins/content/gallery/colorboxCall.js");
        $document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base(). "plugins/content/gallery/colorbox.css");

        preg_match_all('/{dGallery}(.*?){\/dGallery}/is', $article->text, $matches);

        $i=0;

        foreach ($matches[1] as $value)
        {
            $result .= ''; 
            $dir = '/home/juniorwe/public_html/images/'.$matches[1][$i];
            $cdir = scandir($dir); 
            foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
            { 
                if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
                { 
                    if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
                    { 
                        $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
                    }else{ 
                        $result .='<a class="group4" href="../images/'.$matches[1][$i].'/'.$value.'" title=""><img src="../images/'.$matches[1][$i].'/'.$value.'" class="gallery"/></a>';
                    } 
                }
            }
            $article->text = str_replace('{dGallery}'.$matches[1][$i].'{/dGallery}',$result, $article->text); 
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? $matches[1][$i]  ... shouldn't that be $value and I'm not sure what $value[$i] would be since I don't think preg_match_all returns a multidimensional array. Are you sure you are getting a valid folder there? Also why not just use JFilesystem::files($matches[1]) to get the array of files in the folder?

Comment: What I am trying to do is that the page on the site might have multiple occurrences of a string {dGallery}foldername1{/dGallery}, {dGallery}foldername2{/dGallery} and so forth. $matches[1] would have array like array('0'=>'Folder1','1'=>Folder2). I am looping through $match[1] array and another loop inside $matches[1] $match[1][$i=0] is Fo1, Fo2 and read those folders get images and replace {dG..}Fo1{/dG..} string with images.Hope that make sense. Excuse for my English..

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like this

```
public function onContentPrepare($content, $article, $params, $limit)
{

        preg_match_all('/{dGallery}(.*?){\/dGallery}/is', $article->text, $matches);


        foreach ($matches[0] as $folder)
        {

            $result = array(); 

            $dir = '/home/juniorwe/public_html/images/' . $folder; // You might want to get the stored value for image path instead of hard coding

            if (is_dir($dir))
            { 
                 $cdir = JFilesystem::files($dir); 

                 foreach ($cdir as $value) 
                { 
                        $article->text = str_replace('{dGallery}' . $folder .'{/dGallery}','<img src="/images/' . $folder . '/' . $value. ' "/>', $article->text);
                }

            } 

        }
 }
```

Is it that you are trying to get the images from the sub folders also?

Comment: Thanks Elin for your help. The solution works if I have only one image within the folder. I have many images in each folder. I have posted the updated code which works but a bit mess. Thanks..

Comment: Not sure why that would be, the whole point is to use the API to get the array of all impages -- you should not be reinventing that wheel. Also as mentioned you should be checking that the $dir exists and not hard coding the path.